# FormatException on Filling a datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

There is always a `FormatException` thrown in this line of code, it says:

> Input String was not in a correct format.

Here's the code:

```
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType =CommandType.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DriverID, FirstName, LastName FROM Driver WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName or DriverID = @DriverID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmployeeFN.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmployeeLN.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DriverID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmpID.Text;
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        adp.SelectCommand = cmd;

        DataTable Mydt = new DataTable();

        adp.Fill(Mydt); <===Here is the line where the exception is

        con.Close();
```

Comment: Is `DriverID` an integer type field in your table?

Comment: we need the definition of your datatable, and possibly of your table in my sql

Comment: Is `DriverID` a VarChar?

Comment: I may be wrong here but doesn't MySQL use `?` for parameters rather than named parameters? I haven't touched the DAL that uses MySQL in a while and can't get to the code for another 8ish hours but if I recall correctly I had to use `?` for each parameter then add the parameters in the "correct order" based on what order the ?'s appear left to right.

Comment: @Frito No, I've used Connector and you can use named parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need both AddWithValue and `.Value`. Use:

```
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtEmployeeFN.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtEmployeeLN.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DriverID", txtEmpID.Text);
```

If you want to enforce type, use `Add`:

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmployeeFN.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmployeeLN.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DriverID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmpID.Text;
```

Check to make sure your table fields are all VarChars, by the way.

Comment: This looks like the way I do it with ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

use `AddWithValue` like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DriverID, FirstName, LastName FROM Driver WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName or DriverID = @DriverID";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtEmployeeFN.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtEmployeeLN.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DriverID", txtEmpID.Text);
```

But please note that if you are using **ODBC**, you can't use named parameters. You have to use positional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things that could be problems:

```
SELECT DriverID, FirstName, LastName 
FROM Driver 
WHERE FirstName = @FirstName 
    AND LastName = @LastName 
    or DriverID = @DriverID
```

1. Is DriverID an integer?  If so the parameter type should be an integer, not a `VarChar`
2. If `@DriverID` is not a valid integer value in string format, it could raise this exception
3. Your where clause is probably invalid.  You should group the contition you are `OR`ing:

```
  WHERE (FirstName = @FirstName 
    AND LastName = @LastName)
    or DriverID = @DriverID
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add parameters like this, you should simply try this :-

```
cmd.CommandText = string.format(
"SELECT DriverID, FirstName, LastName 
FROM Driver WHERE FirstName = {0} AND LastName = {1} OR DriverID = {2}", 
txtEmployeeFN.Text.trim(),txtEmployeeLN.Text.trim(), txtEmpID.Text.trim());
```

If the Input String is still an incorrect format then you have a syntax issue.

Why not open Server Explorer in Visual Studio and a create Query on the Data Connection you have made, that mimics what your doing in code.

Visual Studio will show you the SQL query text that you need to use in your code.

Comment: What if there is a single quote in `txtEmployeeFN.Text`

Comment: The above method should help establish if there's a fault in how he has his parameters setup. He needs to find the root of the issue, so if he tries it this way and it works he knows where to look.

Comment: That is true, but there is a risk that this code ends up in a production environment if we don't tell about the risk of sql injection